# Indenting parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2016

Does anyone know how to indent a parameter name in SSRS 2016?  It looks like it works when I run the report locally, but it doesn't on the server.  I indented it with the space bar.

Local:

[image]

Server:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this to show it as a sub-parameter of `Corporate Entity`?  If so, you could use [Box Drawing Characters](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2500-257F) to show your hierarchies:

```
Corporate Entity
├─Coordinator
├─Location
└─Practitioners
```

Comment: How do I draw the box drawing characters?

Comment: I used your idea to just add "---" to create the indentation.

Comment: @jackstraw22  You go to the website I linked to in my answer, highlight the one you want to use and then copy and paste.  They are the same as any other character you can type on your keyboard.

Comment: That makes logical sense.  Of course, I was just told not to bother indenting.  But this is good to know for future reference.

Comment: @jackstraw22  No worries.  For the benefit of any future users that come across this same question, if this was the correct answer for you situation please mark my answer as such.